# SQL-Server: send ONE mail from more SQL-Servers on different Win Servers

Tags: sql-server, email, operators, windows-server

I have different SQL-Servers installed on different Windows Servers. Each SQL-Server have a maintenance plan and now I am adding the e-mail function. That means I get e-mails from every SQL-Server. But I want just ONE e-mail, if that´s possible.

Is there a way to configure e-mail over all SQL-Servers to get only one?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible in SQL Server out of the box.

You'll either need an external application to do this, or maybe make some script that can run on one SQL Agent that checks the state of jobs on all the servers. Of course if the server that ran on failed, you'd get no notification.

I'd go with an external powershell script, a good example can be found on [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlsandwiches/2012/01/29/find-failed-sql-jobs-with-powershell/).